# Why does the Sleep() function behave like this?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm playing around with the `Sleep()` function in C++ right now, and I am not understanding why this code operates the way it does.

I made a program to find the difference between two times, but it is not working as expected.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int timeA = (int)chrono::system_clock::now;
    cout << timeA << "\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) Sleep(1000);

    int timeB = (int)chrono::system_clock::now;
    cout << timeB << "\n";

    int timeDifference = timeB - timeA;
    cout << timeDifference;

    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

It seems as if the program is setting the variables at the same time, and then sleeping. Is this the case? If so, help me to understand why, please.

Comment: You forgot to call the function: `now` -> `now()`.

Comment: My rule of thumb: Whenever I see a C-style cast like `(int)` I assume the programmer <expletive deleted>ed up and traded a compiler error for a runtime error and inspect the code closely. If you follow a similar strategy and treat C-style casts (and `reinterpret_cast`) with suspicion you will likely save time debugging in the long run.

Comment: If you find that adding an arbitrary cast like `(int)` "fixes" the problem, the cast usually becomes the source of a new problem and does nothing to fix the original problem.

Answer (score 3):

`now` is a *function*, not an attribute or variable. You failed to call it, and are casting the function pointer itself to `int`, which will always produce the same value for a given run (on a typical 64 bit system, the low 32 bits of the address where `now` is located).

Change both lines to use `chrono::system_clock::now()`, not `chrono::system_clock::now`.

Note that this is one of the reasons to avoid C-style casts, as well as a reason to compile with warnings turned up; it protects you from casting to wildly incorrect end results, without at least some sort of alert.

Comment: Thanks for that, didn't notice the difference. How could I output the timepoint in ostream as an integer value then?

Comment: Try `(timeB - timeA).count()`. You may need to use `duration_cast` if you want to change the units.